# In the rust test, I don't care about the sequence of vec![]. What should i do?

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofJeL.png)

Is there any disorderd arrays Or Do not judge the order when asserting?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), You should also take the [tour] and read [ask], then [edit] your question and add a [mre] as text in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is [`sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort) both sides in the assert call itself. This only works if `T` implements [`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html).

```rs
let result = my_function();
my_function.sort();
let target = vec![];
target.sort();

assert_eq!(result, target);
```

If your datatype does not support Ord, you can use [`sort_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort_by) with a FnMut that returns an instance of [`Ordering`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html).

Note that this can have issues when there isn't one specific way a vector can be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `Vec`(s) to `HashBag`(s) that contains references to the items in the `Vec`s. That will disregard the order of items when asserting for equality:

```ini
[dependencies]
hashbag = "0.1.9"
```

```rust
#[test]
fn two_vecs_equal_independent_of_item_order() {
    use hashbag::HashBag;

    let actual = vec![1, 2, 3, 3];

    let expected_fail = vec![3, 2, 1];

    assert_ne!(
        actual.iter().collect::<HashBag<&i32>>(),
        expected_fail.iter().collect::<HashBag<&i32>>()
    );

    let expected_pass = vec![3, 2, 1, 3];

    assert_eq!(
        actual.iter().collect::<HashBag<&i32>>(),
        expected_pass.iter().collect::<HashBag<&i32>>()
    );

}
```

Comment: Note that this fails when a vector has multiple equivalent values

Comment: Good catch! I updated the answer to use `HashBag` instead of `HashSet`, which will solve that problem.